# Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(no such table: Prospect (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR):

Tags: flutter, sqlite

Error:

> Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(no such table: Prospect (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Prospect (id, nombre_nucleo, nombre_contacto, municipio_prospecto, telefono_prospecto, email_prospecto, observaciones_prospecto, fecha_alta, status_pros, hectareas_Aprox) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, ?, ?)) sql 'INSERT INTO Prospect (id, nombre_nucleo, nombre_contacto, municipio_prospecto, telefono_prospecto, email_prospecto, observaciones_prospecto, fecha_alta, status_pros, hectareas_Aprox) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, ?, ?)' args [nombre, nombre largo muy largo, Guadalajara, 3314550167, myrnamares90@gmail.com, qwertyuiopñlkjhgfdsazxcvbnmklñpasdcfv, true, 100.0]}

Tengo algunos problemas con mi código para enviar datos a mi *db* de *sqlite*,y en la *db* no sé si el *insert* esta bien, no sé cual utilizar o si ambas son correctas y lo que esta fallando es mi forma de enviar los datos.

prospectPage:

```
class ProspectPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _ProspectPageState createState() => _ProspectPageState();
}

class _ProspectPageState extends State<ProspectPage> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final scaffolKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final prospectProvider = new ProspectProvider();

  ProspectModel prospect = new ProspectModel();

  bool _saving = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Nuevo prospecto'),
        actions: [],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          //form como en Html
          child: Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                new Image.asset(
                  'assets/img/logo.png',
                  width: 200.0,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                _nombreNucleo(),
                _botonSubmit(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _nombreNucleo() 

    return TextFormField(
      
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Nombre núcleo',
        icon: Icon(Icons.grass),
      ),
      onSaved: (value) => prospect.nombreNucleo = value,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.length < 5) {
          return 'Ingresar nombre del núcleo minimo 5 letras';
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    );
  }

 

  Widget _botonSubmit() {

    return RaisedButton.icon(
      onPressed: _submit,
      icon: Icon(Icons.save),
      label: Text('Guardar'),
    );
  }

  void _submit() async {
    
    await DBProvider.db.newProspect(prospect);
    print('se guardo el prospecto');
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  void mostrarSnackbar(String mensaje) {

    final snackbar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(mensaje),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
    );
    scaffolKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackbar);
  }
}
```

database:

```
class DBProvider {
  
  static Database _database;
  
  static final DBProvider db = DBProvider._();
  
  DBProvider._();

 
  Future<Database> get database async {

    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await initDB();
    return _database;
  }

  
  Future<Database> initDB() async {
    

    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    final path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'ProspectsDB.db');
    print(path);

    
    return await openDatabase(

      path,
      version: 1,
      onOpen: (db) {},
      onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
        //query
        await db.execute(" CREATE TABLE Prospect("
            "id INTEGER(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            "nombre_nucleo TEXT(255) NOT NULL,"
            ")");
      },
    );
  }

  Future<int> newProspect(ProspectModel newProspect) async {

    final db = await database;
    final resp = await db.insert("Prospect", newProspect.toJson());
    print(resp);
    return resp;
  }

  Future<List<ProspectModel>> getAllProspects() async {

    final db = await database;
    final resp = await db.query('Prospect');

    return resp.isNotEmpty
        ? resp.map((p) => ProspectModel.fromJson(p)).toList()
        : [];
  }

  Future<ProspectModel> getProsId(int id) async {

    final db = await database;
    final resp = await db.query('Prospect', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);

    return resp.isNotEmpty ? ProspectModel.fromJson(resp.first) : null;
  }

  Future<List<ProspectModel>> getProsForDate(int fecha_alta) async {

    final db = await database;
    final resp = await db.rawQuery('''
    SELECT * FROM Prospect WHERE fecha_alta = '$fecha_alta'
    ''');

    return resp.isNotEmpty
        ? resp.map((p) => ProspectModel.fromJson(p)).toList()
        : [];
  }

  Future<int> updatePros(ProspectModel newProspect) async {

    final db = await database;
    final resp = await db.update('Prospect', newProspect.toJson(),
        where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [newProspect.id]);

    return resp;
  }

  Future<int> deletePros(int id) async {

    final db = await database;
    final resp = await db.delete('Prospect', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);

    return resp;
  }
}
```

Otra forma de *insert*:

```
Future<int> newProspect(ProspectModel newProspect) async {
    final id = newProspect.id;

    final nombreNucleo = newProspect.nombreNucleo;

    //verificar la db
    final db = await database;

    final resp = await db.rawInsert(
      '''
      INSERT INTO Prospect( '$id', '$nombreNucleo')
    ''',
    );

    return resp;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que devolvía era porque no se estaba creando la tabla en la base de datos, creaba el archivo .db, pero estaba vacío, al igual este error lo tuve mientras utilice el emulador de android, cambie a hacer mis pruebas en un dispositivo físico y en este si crea la tabla correctamente dentro de la DB, al igual para poder extraer la DB de la url que regresa flutter, lo pude hacer instalando los comando adb, hasta que hice esto pude ver que la DB estaba vacía, dejo el comando adb:

adb -d shell "run-as com.example.xicaras_app cat /data/user/0/com.example.xicaras_app/app_flutter/XicarasDB.db" > XicarasDB.db

Este comando me ayudo a extraer el archivo, no lo pude ver en DB browser pero al extraerlo venia en 0, no creaba la tabla, y al abrirlo en un bloc de notas estaba vacío.

Answer (score 0):

No veo que otras querys estas usando,pero al menos esta:

```
'''
  INSERT INTO Prospect( '$id', '$nombreNucleo')
'''
```

diria que esta mal formulada,te faltan los campos de la tabla donde van a ir insertados los valores.

```
"INSERT INTO NombreTabla(campo1,campo2....) VALUES ( valor1,valor2.....)"
```

los valores no numericos irian entrecomillados.Vigila no mezclar las comillas de la query con las comillas de los valores.
Por otro lado ,viendo los errores,parece que dice que no encuentra la tabla Prospect,verifica que la tabla esta en la db con el mismo nombre que usas.Tambien veo esto en el error:

```
VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, ?, ?)' args [nombre, nombre    largo muy largo, Guadalajara, 3314550167, myrnamares90@gmail.com, qwertyuiopñlkjhgfdsazxcvbnmklñpasdcfv, true, 100.0]}
```

Los valores tipo texto deberian ir entrecomillados en el array args.